# Matlab: Accessing hidden parameters in function handles

Tags: matlab, function, anonymous

When an anonymous function is defined in Matlab, it internally stores the variables which is using from the workspace.
for example

A=2

f=@(x) x^A

clear A

Now if you call f(2) you get the result 4.
If you just print f or convert it to string you will get

@(x)x^A

My question is how to access the internal variable *A* in the function?

Comment: Not sure there is a way to recover `A` after you cleared it from memory. You could always calculate `f(x)` for different `x` values, then solve you equation for `A`, but the simplest I think is to not define an anonymous function with temporary named variables. Just define it explicitly `f=@(x) x^2`. Keep the use of named variables only for the cases where they represent constants that you can infer easily (for example: `Gravity = 9.81 ; F=@(m) -m*Gravity ;`, even if I clear `Gravity` from the workspace, I will still have a good idea of what my function is doing)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is using the `functions` command.

```
fa = functions(f);
```

The output is a structure which includes `workspace`, a cell array containing a structure containing your variables, in this case:

```
ws = fa.workspace{1};
ws.A   % returns "2"
```

Comment: That's neat. It make sense that functions carry a workspace with them, but I never realized that you could completely deplete your available memory (by embedding large arrays in your anonymous function), and finding the culprit would be difficult because their memory size doesn't appear with the classic `whos` command.